# Multiple Choice Questions

Tags: calculus

I took an exam recently in which I have some query regarding some multiple choice questions.

$(i)~$Let $f :\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function with $f(0)=0$. If $~\forall~x\in \mathbb R, 1 < f~'(x)<2,$ then on $(0,\infty)$:

A. $f$ is unbounded

B. $f$ is increasing and bounded

C. $f$ has at least one zero.

D. $f$ is periodic

> **Attempt**: I took the example of $f(x)=1.5x$ which is unbounded,so, the correct answer should be **A**?

$(ii)$ Let $S= \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} ([0,\dfrac {1}{2n+1}] \bigcup [\dfrac {1}{2n}, 1])$. Then, which one of the following statements is **false**

A. There exist sequences $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}$ in $[0,1]$, such that $S=[0,1] - \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (a_n,b_n) $.

B. $[0,1] - S$ is an open set.

C. If $A$ is an infinite subset of $S$, then $A$ has a limit point.

D. There exists an infinite subset of $S$ having no limit points.

> **Attempt**: I think that last statement **D. There exists an infinite subset of $S$ having no limit points.** should be false as it violates Bolzanno's Limit theorem.

Was I right in my attempts? Thank you very much for your help in this regard.

Comment: For the first question, your example case disproves **B**, **C**, and **D**, so you are correct.

Comment: I notice you added the coefficient $>1$, was just about to mention that.

Comment: Yeah. It struck me as I was reading through.:)

Comment: What does the notation $([a,b],[c,d])$ mean?

Comment: @Regret It means $S= \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} ([0,\dfrac {1}{2n+1}] \bigcup [\dfrac {1}{2n}, 1])$. Though, I have edited it now to show the real meaning

Comment: Your example for the first question does the job. A more technical approach would be to say that for $x\gt0$ we have - for some $0\lt y \lt x$ - that $f(x)-f(0)=(x-0)f'(y)\ge x$ - a simple application of the mean value theorem.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thank you for the response. Could you please confirm for the second one as well. Thanks again